# creating a dynamic editing tool in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to python.
I am trying to create a GUI that can be used edit an image namely, cropping and changing colour of background of the image, using wxpython.

Can someone guide me where i can find information to tackle this? I have taken a look at the wx wiki but there isnt much on dynamic widgets that can be used to do this.

Many thanks, 
HP

– Dilettant Jun 9 at 10:02 - Could you give more detail on what dynamic here means, as you were able, to detect that the wxpython wiki does not provide anything similar. Only you may be able to explicate that. And than maybe someone here can jump in, and give hints.

– user6444620 1 hour ago I looked into using PIL, but it doesn't seem to support STL files so i can not get it to show/display. What i am using is VTK to render a 3d image and display it using wxpython. i've got it to display using wxpython i now need a method to to create a editing tool to perform - mentioned earlier. Still doing more research to find best method to tackle, unfortunately to no avil at the moment.

Comment: Could you give more detail on what dynamic here means, as you were able, to detect that the wxpython wiki does not provide anything similar. Only you may be able to explicate that. And than maybe someone here can jump in, and give hints.

Comment: Hi Dilettant, Dynamic was me trying to say user input via GUI. I would like to create a window that opens a STL (for 3D graphics) file and allows the user(s) to crop and change colour of the image, namely using buttons which will pull up a drawing tool that can be used to manipulate the 3D image.

Comment: Maybe the answer offered helps you on that route?

Comment: I looked into using PIL, but it doesn't seem to support STL files so i can not get it to show/display.  What i am using is VTK to render a 3d image and display it using wxpython. i've got it to display using wxpython i now need a method to to create a editing tool to perform - mentioned earlier. Still doing more research to find best method to tackle, unfortunately to no avil at the moment.

Comment: Please add this info of above two comments to the question, so people "knowing" find the full specification in one place - this usually boostst answering, esp. as in many renderings of the web page, comments are often hidden behind a "display N more comments" like link text ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download wxPython Docs and Demo. https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/3.0.2.0/wxPython3.0-win32-docs-demos-3.0.2.0.exe/download?use_mirror=netassist

These Items maybe help you (Use the search TextCtrl on Left Bottom area):

- GraphicsContext
- PrintFramework
- Mask (Maybe help if use PNG or alpha channel)
- ImageAlpha

To Crop Image you need some Image package, Like a PIL( http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or numpy (http://www.numpy.org/). If you will use PIL, has a nice tutorial in this link:  http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0202/

To use PIL images in wx, this tutorial have some functions to help you: http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages